# self-hosted Gitlab runner register failed x509 certificate signed by unknown authority on GKE with helm install

Tags: gitlab, google-kubernetes-engine, gitlab-ci, x509certificate

I installed Gitlab(version 13.7.1-ee) on GKE with using helm.

and as prerequisites, because of Firewall rule, and having no controllable domain, I cannot use cert-manager's valid certificate. Then I want to use self-signed cert or [wildcard-cert supported by gitlab](https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/tls.html#option-4-use-auto-generated-self-signed-wildcard-certificate).

Gitlab-runner showed error when running.

> status=couldn't execute POST against https://gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io/api/v4/runners: Post https://gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io/api/v4/runners: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority

I tried several ways like,

#### a. [setting envVars](https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-runner/-/issues/3968)

values.yaml

```
gitlab-runner:
  envVars:
    - name: CI_SERVER_TLS_CA_FILE
      value: /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/certs/gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io.crt
    - name: CONFIG_FILE
      value: /home/gitlab-runner/.gitlab-runner/config.toml
```

#### b. use same certificate on gitlab.web-service & gitlab-runner

made self-signed, made on my local machine using

> `openssl genrsa`  command

values.yaml

```
gitlab:
  webservice:
    ingress:
      tls:
        secretName: selfsigned-cert-tls

gitlab-runner:
  runners:
    certsSecretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
```

#### c. create self-signed certificate using cert-manager on GKE and use that cert.

use external cert-manager, and external nginx-ingress-controller (install both by myself using helm) and set

ingress

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: self-ingress
  namespace: gitlab
  annotations:
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: "nginx"
    cert-manager.io/issuer: "selfsigned-issuer"
spec:
  tls:
    - hosts:
      - gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io
      secretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
  rules:
   - host: gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io
    http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          serviceName: gitlab-webservice-default
          servicePort: 8181
        path: /
      - backend:
          serviceName: gitlab-webservice-default
          servicePort: 8080
        path: /admin/sidekiq
```

values.yaml

```
global:
  ingress:
    configureCertmanager: false

nginx-ingress:
  enabled:false

certmanager:
  install: false
```

#### d. using wildcard self signed cert made by gitlab, and use own self-signed cert for gitlab-runner

With this way, using Gitlab-runner is not recommended
https://docs.gitlab.com/charts/installation/tls.html#option-4-use-auto-generated-self-signed-wildcard-certificate

values.yaml

```
certmanager:
  install: false

  ingress:
    configureCertmanager: false

gitlab-runner:
  runners:
    certsSecretName: selfsigned-cert-tls
```

---

but all of those still showed error

> x509: certificate signed by unknown authority
> sometimes x509: certificate is valid for ingress.local and not valid for gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io

---

I totally got lost

- How self-signed cert must be created on GKE ?
- What secret must be set for gitlab-runner ?
- Possibly I cannot use `xip.io` for self-signed-cert ?

I sincerely appreciate your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I fixed this issue, following an article.

[Install GitLab Enterprise on Konvoy](https://archive-docs.d2iq.com/dkp/konvoy/1.8/cicd/gitlab/)

So, using wildcard self signed cert made by gitlab, and get cert data from wildcard-tls-gitlab

```shell
kubectl get secret gitlab-wildcard-tls \
 --template='{{ index .data "tls.crt" }}' | base64 -D > gitlab.crt
```

```shell
kubectl create secret generic gitlab-runner-certs \
 --from-file=gitlab.xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io.crt=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx.xip.io.crt
```

I can use  `gitlab-runner-certs` as gitlab-runner secrets.

and I noticed my value.yaml had mistake

```yaml
gitlab-runner:
  certsSecretName: gitlab-runner-certs # correct
  runners: 
    certsSecretName: gitlab-runner-certs # wrong
```

Comment: You saved me hours of useless search. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I've had a similar issue in the past, and the configuration options for the CA File have never worked for me. What does work is telling the host that runs your gitlab-runner to trust that cert.

You'll likely need both the Root signing cert and the intermediate cert from GKE. I've never used GKE or the cert-manager you mentioned, so you'll research how to get the two certs (or it might be just one if they merge them for you). If you get both separately, you'll have to combine them by taking the text in one of them and putting it in the second (literal copy/paste).

Once you have the file with the root and intermediate certificates, you can follow the directions for your OS for trusting it. This will depend on your OS, but for Centos I've followed the instructions here: https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html. This works for any version of Centos (up to 8 so far), but I'm unsure about the directions for Ubuntu/Debian. https://manuals.gfi.com/en/kerio/connect/content/server-configuration/ssl-certificates/adding-trusted-root-certificates-to-the-server-1605.html

If you're using something other than Centos/Debian-Ubuntu, or the instructions above don't work for Debian/Ubuntu, you'll have to research how to trust the root cert.